# valueForKeyPath: @"@max.self" not work when number is 100

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, max

```
NSArray *vals = {100,100,50,50,50}
maximumValue = [[vals valueForKeyPath: @"@max.self"] intValue];
```

---

Returns

> maximumValue : 50

Comment: Your code is not valid Obj-C.

Comment: how you can directly assign int to nsarray?. Welcome [have a look](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: try __not__ to compare them as `NSString` objects but `NSNumber` objects, becase `@"50"` is greater than `@"100"`, so you should try like e.g. `NSArray *vals = @[@100, @100, @50, @50, @50];`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
NSArray *vals = @[@100,@100,@50,@50,@50];

NSLog(@"%d",[[vals valueForKeyPath: @"@max.self"] intValue]
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an array of strings.  When compared as strings, "50" is greater than "100" because 5 comes after 1.  You need to convert to integers first, then take the max.

Unfortunately, ObjC doesn't have the `map` function, so you need to do it manually.

```
NSMutableArray *intArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *val in vals) {
    [intArray addObject:@(val intValue)];
}
maximumValue = [[intArray valueForKeyPath: @"@max.self"] intValue];
```

**Edit**

Based on Sulthan's suggestion, you can also do the following:

```
NSArray *a = @[ @"50", @"100" ];
NSLog(@"%@", [[a valueForKeyPath:@"intValue"] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"]);
```

The first call to `valueForKeyPath:@"intValue"` gives an array of `NSNumber`s.  At this point, the `@max.self` key-path gives the expected value, as a numeric comparison is made between elements.

Comment: `[NSArray valueForKey:]` can be used as `map` in Objective-C. Also, if your guess is true, you can just use `@"@max.intValue"` on the original array.

Comment: That does not appear to be true.  `NSArray *a = @[ @"50", @"100" ];
 NSLog(@"%@", [a valueForKey:@"max.intValue"]);` does not work.

Comment: You are missing `@` before `max`.

Comment: True.  Added it.  Still crashes.

Comment: `[@[@"0", @"1", @"5", @"10"] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"]`  . You need to use `-valueForKeyPath`.